# Focus file folder location in explorer on click file link Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need functionality on my localhost project.

Using js or html, when someone clicks on the file link, an explorer window opens and that file will be highlighted.

[image: Focus file folder location in explorer on click file link Js]

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to users files or anything outside the browser (like file explorer) with JS or HTML. So it's basically impossible to do what you want.

Comment: Yes I don't want to access file , just i want only focus link location , check screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk2dS.png

Comment: Yes I know what you want to do, but it's not possible.